# Recursive ARIMA regression in R

Tags: r, recursion

I am working on doing a recursive ARIMA regression. I think I am one the right track (see the code below), but have a problem when I put out the coefficients into vectors. Simply put, the coefficient are all the same, whereas the should have been different.

```
rolling.arima <- lapply(seq(72,nrow(udb)), 
function(x) arima(udb.train,
order = c(1,1,0), seasonal = list(order = c(1,0,0), period = 12)))

all_slopes1 <- unlist(sapply(1:42, function(j) rolling.arima[[j]]$coef[1]))
all_slopes2 <- unlist(sapply(1:42, function(j) rolling.arima[[j]]$coef[2]))

plot.ts(all_slopes1)
plot.ts(all_slopes2)
```

Anyone who can spot the problem?

Comment: You're getting the same value because your `lapply` call is doing the same thing for however long `seq(72,nrow(udb))` is. Perhaps, you mean to do something with that local variable `x` inside the call.

Comment: @Abdou thanks for the answer. What I hope to do is a recursive regression. That is, for each new 'x' in the variable a new regression will be run. So I get coefficient that change slightly with every new regression as new information comes in. Do you have any idea about how that could be achieved?

Comment: I am not sure I follow the logic fully, but since nothing changes throughout the iterative `arima()` calls, then your output is likely to remain the same. What do you want to be different at every `arima()`? You can change your training set (`udb.train`) or the inputs to the `seasonal` argument?

Comment: @Abdou. No they won't stay the same. First you estimate using 72 observations. Then you estimate using the first 73 observation, then 74 and so on, up until you have estimated the model with 113 observations. This will thus give you 113-72 different sets of coefficients.

Comment: it would have been quite helpful if you had led with that. I guess the answer provided below should do just fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to update your data in every window. Try something like this:

```
rolling.arima <- lapply(seq(72,length(udb.train)), 
                        function(x) arima(udb.train[1:x],
                                          order = c(1,1,0), seasonal = list(order = c(1,0,0), period = 12)))
lrest<-length(rolling.arima)

all_slopes1 <- unlist(sapply(1:lrest, function(j) rolling.arima[[j]]$coef[1]))
all_slopes2 <- unlist(sapply(1:lrest, function(j) rolling.arima[[j]]$coef[2]))

plot.ts(all_slopes1)
plot.ts(all_slopes2)
```

[image]